# Double/Float output issues in Java Android

Tags: java, android, floating-point, double

In my application, I allowed user to input DOUBLE value (2 decimal places) then total up and display. It works fine with value lesser than 10,000,000; However, when displaying

```
Double totalvalue = 1000000000.50;
Displayed as 1.0E9
Intent to get Display as : 1000000000.50

Double totalvalue = 10000000.00
Displayed as 1.0E7
Intent to get Display as : 10000000.00
```

So my problem is how to get Display the actual value?
p/s: I did research on this issues for few hours but unfortunately I doesn't get any answer for that.

Comment: @boxed__l No, it won't work with "Double.toString()"

Comment: @LoganMurphy The question you reference is about display as an integer, and many of the answers, including the accepted one, would not work for this case.

Comment: ya, toString will simply convert the value as string without changing the format. I applied the solution given and it works fine. 
BTW Thanks all.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan The second answer has a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
String.format("%1$.2f", totalvalue);
```

to format your `Double` without the `E` notation.

Comment: Is it significantly different from "%.2f"?

Comment: @SajalDutta - When there's only one argument to the format, there's no difference at all. I just have a habit of always specifying the position for each format conversion. I see we have identical answers. I started writing my answer, I think, while you were editing your earlier deleted answer, which was considerably different. So +1 to you. :)

Comment: @TedHopp lol.. I really wanted to know aside from multiple arguments with index specifiers if there was any other stuff that I didn't know of. Nothing to do with our answers. Thanks. +1 to you too. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can display as-

```
String.format("%.2f", totalValue)
```